# DNN Create User not notifying user

Tags: dotnetnuke, registration

I am currently trying to work my way around a problem which suddenly popped up in DNN. For some reason whenever I create a new user from the admin settings and ticking notify the user is not receiving the email with heir credentials or anything at all. This used to work for sure a while back don't really know when it stopped working. I tested the SMTP Settings and everything is working fine. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

(using dnn 06.02.03)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the problem was due to the SMTP Server we are using, third party supplier had a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Event Log to see if there are any mail-related errors being reported.

Comment: No mail related errors found, there are some general exceptions but the ones regarding the user creation are all "User Created" without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could also start by looking at your Administrator account, defined on the Admin/Site Settings page. Whatever Admin account (the email address on the profile) is setup there will be the one that emails come from in the DNN site, maybe you have one with a bad email address defined and things are getting blocked because of that.